# How to restrict user from entering duplicate text in multiple text inputs

Tags: c#, java, jquery, html

i have a problem in my site user is filling a form and let suppose there are two textboxes in that form, I want to do that if user enter `"Ahsan"` in first textbox then he is not allowed to enter `"Ahsan"` in second textbox.

Comment: Some HTML and detail of what you've done to date would be useful here.

Comment: i have seen this problem first time and i dont know how to solve this , i googled but found no solution

Comment: I forget to add that i can have multiple textboxes and if i have then what should i do ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGnjZ/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#text1,#text2').change(function() {
        if ($('#text1').val() === $('#text2').val()) {
            alert('text matches');
        }
    });
});​
```

The code uses the [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function to trigger a function on change of either text input (uses the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)) and then compares the values using [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) could be [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) or [keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) or performed on submit of the form using [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

### Update

If you needed to check lots of inputs... then you could use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) :

```
$(function () {
    $('.inputclass').change(function () {
        var $current = $(this);
        $('.inputclass').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == $current.val() && $(this).attr('id') != $current.attr('id')) {
                alert('duplicate found');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this loops each value of inputs using the class `inputclass` and checks for duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#lastInput').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === $('#firstInput').val()) {
        $(this).val('');
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:text').not(':first').on('blur', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    if(value.length) {
        $('input:text').not(this).each(function(){
            if(this.value == value) {
                alert('Error');
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what should i do if i have multiple text box

Answer (score 0):

you can do it something like that:

for example your first textbox id is txt1, and second textbox id is txt2.
you want to restrict 'Ahsan' to type in second textbox.

$(document).ready(function(){

```
 var text1=$('#txt1').text();
 var text2=$('#txt2').text();

 if(text1!text2){
     //do your code
 }
 else {
   alert('value exist in textbox1');
 }
```

})

Comment: This wont work ... [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is for extracting text from a HTML element not getting the value from an input